# NSLayoutConstraint with VFL is working only horizontally when using '|'

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following implementation of a UIView..

```
struct LoginView {
let loginView: UIView = UIView()

func layoutLoginView() -> UIView {
    
    loginView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        loginView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

    return loginView
  } 
}
```

Then, I subview the above in the viewcontroller as below..

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

private let instanceOfLoginView = LoginView()

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    
    view.addSubview(instanceOfLoginView.layoutLoginView())
    
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[loginView]-|", options: [], metrics: [:], views: ["loginView":instanceOfLoginView.layoutLoginView()]))
        
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[loginView]-|", options: [], metrics: [:], views: ["loginView":instanceOfLoginView.layoutLoginView()]))

}
```

The problem is that only the `'H'` side of the NSLayout is working -check the screenshot below-. The `'V'` is not working.

However, when I apply the following `"V:|-8-[loginView]-8-|"`, it works!!!

Could you advise why doesn't the `"V:|-[loginView]-|"` simply work, please..?

Appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using VFL, the `-` character means *"use the standard spacing"*.

In your case:

```
    "H:|-[loginView]-|"
    "V:|-[loginView]-|"
```

you are saying *"use the **layout margins**"* which are, by default:

```
    UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 16.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 16.0)
```

Prior to iOS 11 the `.layoutMargins` of the root view managed by a view controller cannot be changed. To get your purple view to cover the full view, change your VFL to:

```
    "H:|[loginView]|"
    "V:|[loginView]|"
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Truly helpful. Thank you for guiding a newbie like me. Quick question, when saying prior to iOS 11, does this mean this is changing when 11 comes out..?

Comment: Yep - see Apple's docs, or: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/changing-root-view-layout-margins/